# Tuples, Max Value, and Clean Iteration

Tags: python, tuples

This is more out of curiosity than anything, since what I have works. What is the 'cleanest' way to implement this? Given a list of pair-tuples like so `[(Object, int), (Object1, int1), ... ]`, find the maximum int and return the int and object associated with that value.

I did the 'easy way out' as so:

```
bestObject, bestVal = None, 0
for i in range(len(tuple_list)):
    obj, val = tuple_list[i]
    if val > bestVal:
        bestObject, bestVal = obj, val
return bestObject, bestValue
```

Can it be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max will compare the first items in a tuple, so how about:

```
max_val, max_obj = max([(val, obj) for obj, val in tuple_list])
return max_obj, max_val
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Good thinking. I still have trouble with "nested" `for a, b in for y, z` functionality in python.

Answer (score 4):

The `max` function provides a `key` parameter where you can specify exactly what you want to use in your comparisons. For instance:

```
In [1]: class MyObject(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, a):
   ...:         self.a = a
   ...:         

In [2]: a = MyObject('something')

In [3]: b = MyObject('something else')

In [4]: c = MyObject('another thing??')

In [5]: tups = [(a, 1), (b, 5), (c, 2)]

In [6]: max(tups, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[6]: (<__main__.MyObject at 0x26c17d0>, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoroughness, although a bit more confusing than I hoped.

Comment: @Clever No problem :) The idea is that the `key` function provides a special way to determine the `max`. If you had something like `('cat', 4), ('dog', 2), ('monkey', 1)`, taking the normal max would return `('monkey', 1)` because `monkey` is the largest 'value' when sorting the strings. If you instead wanted to find the max based on the number element of the tuple, you use `key` and then a function that pulls out what you want to use. Here we use `lambda x: x[1]`, which means 'when you get an item from this list, compare it based on the second item in the tuple). This returns `('cat', 4)`.

Comment: Ah, that helps. Say I had a dictionary mapping `{ id_ : [val1, val2, val3]}`. How might I apply this same technique to "look through all the val[0] indexes in the dictionary" and return the maximum?

Comment: @Clever So when you use `max` with a dictionary, it will use the keys as the items over which to iterate. So you could do something like `max(d, key=lambda x: x[0])` to get the key of the max value, and then plug that key back into your dictionary (to get the corresponding value) and grab the first element of the result (`k = max(d, key=lambda x: x[0]); val = d[k][0]`). If you just wanted the value (and didn't care about the key), you could do `max(d.values(), key=lambda x: x[0])`. Does that make sense?